# I have noises coming from house

Tags: plumbing

I recently have been hearing thumping noises. They are 4 or 5 in a row. I believe that they are coming from my pipes. Could it be my water pump or sump pump going

Answer (score 1):

not a lot of love on this question so far. It isn't likely to be your pump going out. The pipes will expand and contract as they heat and cool (you run the hot water, the pipe heats up and gets longer, then it cools back down and shrinks). The thumping noise could just be the pipe shifting, especially if it's in tight contact with some framing inside a wall somewhere, so a little pressure builds up, then it slips, then a little more pressure, then it slips again, etc.

Or one of the water lines might be moving and bumping against a wall as water is flowing through it, especially if it's something like PEX and isn't secured everywhere that it's supposed to be, but it could also happen with metal pipe and wouldn't necessarily mean you have a problem, aside from the noises.

Another phenomenon is hammering, where the sudden pressure change when a water outlet is shut off causes the pipe to shift suddenly and creates a hammering sound.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the conduit is caulked closed in your well. It could be pressure in well,forcing air into conduit and that rattling in basement walls.